# Excel Formula to Translate Text into Target Language

Tags: microsoft-excel, translation

I'm looking for a built-in Excel Formula Function to translate text into a target language. I see Google has made a function "GoogleTranslate()" available and was wondering if something equivalent were available for Microsoft Excel?

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't a built in function for it, but you could make your own. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically but you can actually activate the "translate" feature in your Review ribbon bar.

To do that, take the following steps:
Click on 
"File"
"Options"
"Customize Ribbon"
In the right box, make sure "Review" is checked
In the drop down of the left box, whcih that might read "Popular Commands", click and select "All Commands"
Find Translate and click on it.
Then click on the "Add>>" button.

Click on OK and you will have the function in your Review ribbon bar.  Not as slick but it will work if you have the translator service activated.